# While loop requires boolean but found int

Tags: java, android, incompatibletypeerror

I have been stuck on this for ages. On the click of a button in Android Studio I want the value of an integer (called PageNo) to increase by 1. I want different text to appear in the TextView box (Act2PageNo) depending on the value.  Eg if PageNo=2 then Act2PageNo will give a description of Option 2 of a particular product.
However, it is not recognising my code in the While loop saying that my 'while (PageNo=1)' section has provided an integer but requires a Boolean. Also mentions incompatible types.

My code is below: All help appreciated.

```
package com.example.wma76143.testappactivitychange;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView Act2Title;
Button btnnNext;
Button btnPrevious;
private TextView Act2PageNo;
private int PageNo = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        Act2Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Act2PageNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPageNo);
        btnnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        btnPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrevious);


        btnnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                PageNo++;
                Gotonextpage();}

        });
    }
    public void Gotonextpage() {
        while (PageNo=1){
           Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 1");
        }
        while (PageNo=2){
            Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 2");
        }
        while (PageNo=3){
            Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 3");
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Boolean comparisons use `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Your assigning when using `=`, to check you need to use double equal signs `==`

Answer (score 2):

Use the expression `PageNo==1` for comparison. Using `PageNo=1` would return 1, which is of type `int`. A `while` expression needs a boolean condition to evaluate. So, use `PageNo==1` which is the equality operator and returns either `true` or `false`, of type `boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll simply need to use the equality operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`. This will evaluate your expression as a boolean as desired:

```java
public void Gotonextpage() {
  while (PageNo == 1){
    Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 1");
  }
  while (PageNo == 2){
    Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 2");
  }
  while (PageNo == 3){
    Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 3");
  }
}
```

That being said - I think what you desire here is an `if` statement as a `while` block will loop until the condition is false, and in this particular case - loop forever. So:

```java
public void Gotonextpage() {
  if (PageNo == 1) {
    Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 1");
  }
  if (PageNo == 2) {
    Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 2");
  }
  if (PageNo == 3) {
    Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 3");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add one more equal

like this

```
while(PageNo==1){
  // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as your error says that while loop accepts the boolean values, not the integer or any other values.
In your code you can use either !=, ==, >=, <= values for checking the condition(Because the while loop meant for the conditional check).
Instead of your above code, you can change like as shown below.

```
public void Gotonextpage() {
    while (PageNo == 1){
        Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 1");
    }
    while (PageNo == 2){
        Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 2");
    }
    while (PageNo == 3){
        Act2PageNo.setText("Text will be put here to describe Option 3");
    }    
}
```

Please update your code, with boolean conditions for while loops.

Comment: Just punched the air in delight!! Thanks all - now sorted thanks to your help!